# how can I get the ip address of the request in a regested function of python xmlrpc server

Tags: python, call, ip, xml-rpc

I'm writing a simple xmlrpc programe in python. something like the following:

```
def foo(data):

    # I want get the calling client's IP address here... How can I ?

server=SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((host, port))
server.register_function(foo)

server.handle_request()
```

As can be seen in the above, I want to get the client IP address in the registed function "foo", how can I ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do so by subclassing the server (and possibly the handler, too).  E.g.:

```
class MyXMLRPCServer(SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    def process_request(self, request, client_address):
        self.client_address = client_address
        return SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer.process_request(
            self, request, client_address)

server=SimpleXMLRPCServer.MyXMLRPCServer((host, port))
```

Now server.client_address gives you the desired data.  Note that this direct, short coding only works for the single-threaded case (which you're using anyway by choosing the simple server in your code) -- the need to work with the handler comes in if you want to go multi-threaded.

Comment: thank you Alex. But how can I access the instance varible "client_address" in the registed function "foo" ?

Comment: @john, `server.client_address`, of course -- the instance is named `server`, so its instance variables are accessed as `server.whatever`.

Comment: this is slighly better than to instantiate the request handler, bind such client_address to the server instance is easier to access, which I had a similar reqeust, to let regist functions behave differently based on client side ip address, for other's reference.